# Deleting List Item With A Binding Boolean Value - SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

In my app, I have a screen where the user can switch filters (of a map) on and off using the Swift `Toggle`, and also, delete them (with `Edit Button`). I use a `Binding` Boolean variable to connect the toggles so that I can react to each change, here is the code:

```
//The filter data model
class DSFilter{
    
    var filterId : Int
    var filterTitle : String
    var isActive : Bool
    
    
    init(filterId : Int, filterTitle : String, isActive : Bool){
        self.filterId = filterId
        self.filterTitle = filterTitle
        self.isActive = isActive
    }
}

//The data model representable
struct filterItem : View {
    @Binding var filter : DSFilter
    @Binding var isOn : Bool
    @State var image = Image("defPerson")
    
    var body : some View {
        HStack {
            image.resizable().frame(width: 45, height: 45).clipShape(Circle())
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text(filter.filterTitle).font(Font.custom("Quicksand-Bold",size: 15))
                Text(filter.filterTitle).font(Font.custom("Quicksand-Medium",size: 13)).foregroundColor(.gray)
            }.padding(.leading)
            Spacer()
            HStack{
                Toggle("",isOn: $isOn).padding(.trailing, 5).onReceive([self.isOn].publisher.first()) { (value) in
                    self.filter.isActive = self.isOn
                }.frame(width: 30)
            }
        }.frame(height: 60)
            .onAppear(){
                self.isOn = self.filter.isActive             
        }
    }
}

//The view where the user has the control
struct FilterView: View {
    @State var otherFilters : [addedFilter] = []
    @Binding var isActive : Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Capsule().fill(Color.black).frame(width: 50, height: 5).padding()
            ZStack{
                HStack{
                    Spacer()

                    Text("Filters").font(Font.custom("Quicksand-Bold", size: 20))

                    Spacer()
                }.padding()
                HStack{
                    Spacer()
                    
                    EditButton()
                    
                }.padding()
            }

                List{
                    
                    ForEach(0..<self.otherFilters.count, id:\.self){ i in
                        
                        filterItem(filter: self.$otherFilters[i].filter, isOn: self.$otherFilters[i].isOn)
                    }.onDelete(perform:removeRows)
                   
   
                
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
    
    func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        print("deleting")
                    print("deleted filter!")
            self.otherFilters.remove(at: Array(offsets)[0]) //I use it like so because you can only delete 1 at a time anyway
       
        
    }
}

//The class I use to bind the isOn value so I can react to change
struct addedFilter : Identifiable{
    var id : Int
    var filter : DSFilter
    var isOn : Bool
    
    init(filter : DSFilter){
        self.id = Int.random(in: 0...100000)
        self.filter = filter
        self.isOn = filter.isActive
    }
}
```

When I use the delete as it is right now I get the following error (`Xcode 12.0`):

```
Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
2020-10-06 17:42:12.567235+0300 Hynt[5207:528572] Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444
```

What do I need to change so I can delete the items? Should I take a different approach to the `Binding` problem with the `Toggle`?

Comment: Since you're trying to delete at index 0, the array is empty. As in, length = 0.

Comment: Im not trying to delete in index 0, Im deleting at the first index in the offsets array (can be 0 but not have to be), and the array is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a lot of try and fail I came to the answer.
The problem seems to be in the binding part - the compiler can't handle a change in the array size if I bind an element from it so I did the following:
First, I change the `filterItem struct` so the filter property is `@State` and not `@Binding` :

```
struct filterItem : View {
    @State var filter : DSFilter
    @Binding var isOn : Bool
```

Secondly, I have changed the `addedFilter struct` to the following:

```
struct addedFilter : Identifiable{
    var id : Int
    var isOn : Bool
    
    init(filter : DSFilter){
        self.id = filter.filterId
        self.isOn = filter.isActive
    }
}
```

And the `ForEach` loop to the following:

```
ForEach(0..<self.normOthFilters.count, id:\.self){ i in
                        filterItem(filter: self.normOthFilters[i], isOn: self.$otherFilters[i].isOn)
                    }.onDelete(perform:removeRows)
```

To the main view I have added :

```
    @State var normDefFilters : [DSFilter] = []
    @State var normOthFilters : [DSFilter] = []
```

And finally the onDelete function to the following:

```
func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        print("deleting")
            print("deleted filter!")
            self.normOthFilters.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        
    }
```

In conclution I am not changing the value of the binded value and so I am not receiving any errors!

Answer (score 3):

Hi instead of keeping three different array to manage addedFilter, DSFilter, isOn. why don't you try the following **one single model**

```
class FFilter: Identifiable {
var id: Int
 var addedFilter: addedFilter
var dsFilter: DSFilter
var isOn: Bool

init(addedFilter: addedFilter, dsFilter: DSFilter, isOn: Bool) {
    self.id = addedFilter.id
    self.addedFilter = addedFilter
    self.dsFilter = dsFilter
    self.isOn = isOn
}
```

}

**And ViewModel change code like this:**

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var superFilters: [FFilter] = [
    FFilter(
        addedFilter: addedFilter(
            filter: DSFilter(filterId: 1, filterTitle: "Title1", isActive: true)
        ),
        dsFilter: DSFilter(filterId: 1, filterTitle: "Title1", isActive: true),
        isOn: true),
    FFilter(
        addedFilter: addedFilter(
            filter: DSFilter(filterId: 2, filterTitle: "Title2", isActive: false)
        ),
        dsFilter: DSFilter(filterId: 2, filterTitle: "Title2", isActive: false),
        isOn: false),
    FFilter(
        addedFilter: addedFilter(filter: DSFilter(filterId: 3, filterTitle: "Title3", isActive: true)),
        dsFilter: DSFilter(filterId: 3, filterTitle: "Title3", isActive: true),
        isOn: true),
    FFilter(
        addedFilter: addedFilter(
            filter: DSFilter(filterId: 4, filterTitle: "Title4", isActive: true)
        ),
        dsFilter: DSFilter(filterId: 4, filterTitle: "Title4", isActive: true),
        isOn: true),
    FFilter(
        addedFilter: addedFilter(
            filter: DSFilter(filterId: 5, filterTitle: "Title5", isActive: false)
        ),
        dsFilter: DSFilter(filterId: 5, filterTitle: "Title5", isActive: false),
        isOn: false)
]}
```

**then change your list code**

```
  List {
 ForEach(viewModel.superFilters) { filter in
      filterItem(filter: .constant(filter.dsFilter), isOn: .constant(filter.isOn))
      }.onDelete(perform: removeRows(at:)) }
```

**and removeRows method:**

```
func removeRows(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    print("deleting at \(offsets)")
    self.viewModel.superFilters.remove(atOffsets: offsets)}
```

I hope it will work. let me know if you still face any issues

Comment: And still there is a Room for refactoring on DSFilter model you can use it for once.

Comment: This works! but there is only one thing:
I want my users to be able to switch the filters on and off and with the way you said its impossible, how can I change it?

Comment: @TheMachineX if I look at your filter models. addedFilter and DSFilter. both does the same job. am saying instead of keeping same stuff in two different models. Simply create one simple model where it holds filter is ON or OFF. so create one custom getter property from your array, simply iterate which ever is on or off. you can a call however you want. Let me know if you face any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to change your line in `removeRows()` function from

```
self.otherFilters.remove(at: Array(offsets)[0]
```

to

```
self.otherFilters.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
```